# unable to make plotOptions.scatter.states.hover.marker in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot

[According](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.states.hover.marker) to HighCharts API, `plotOptions.scatter.states.hover.marker` manages the appearance of all markers belonging to the hovered series.
However, in the following toy example (JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/17/)), I'm unable to change the appearance of all the markers belonging to the hovering series (for example, changing their color to green).
What is the issue?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                lineWidth:1,
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    symbol:'circle',
                    fillColor: '#800000'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidthPlus: 2,
                        marker: {
                            enabled:true,
                            lineColor: '#00ff00',
                            fillColor: '00ff00',
                            lineWidth: 5
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        color: "#b0b0b0",
        data: [[38,42],[39,39],[35,45],[35,54],{x:36,y:35}]
        }, {
        name: 'B',
        color: "#b0b0b0",
        data: [[46,56],[47,67],[48,69],[50,55],{x:52,y:57}]
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how you could get confused.  This was deprecated, but the documentation doesn't show it on the page you linked to.  If you look here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.states.hover , you'll see marker is deprecated in this object.

You want `plotOptions.scatter.marker.states.hover`

http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/23/

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      scatter: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
          radius: 1,
          symbol: 'circle',
          fillColor: '#800000',
          states: {
            hover: {
              lineColor: '#00ff00',
              fillColor: '#00ff00',
              lineWidth: 5
            }
          }
        },
        states: {
          hover: {
            lineWidthPlus: 2
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'A',
      color: "#b0b0b0",
      data: [
        [38, 42],
        [39, 39],
        [35, 45],
        [35, 54], {
          x: 36,
          y: 35
        }
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      color: "#b0b0b0",
      data: [
        [46, 56],
        [47, 67],
        [48, 69],
        [50, 55], {
          x: 52,
          y: 57
        }
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

EDIT:
To change all the markers on hover, use the `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events

```
series: [{
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      this.update({
        marker: {
          radius: 5,
          fillColor: 'green'
        }
      });
    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      this.update({
        marker: {
          radius: 3,
          fillColor: 'red'
        }
      });
    }
  },
  name: 'A',
  color: "#b0b0b0",
  data: [
    [38, 42],
    [39, 39],
    [35, 45],
    [35, 54], {
      x: 36,
      y: 35
    }
  ]
}, {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      this.update({
        marker: {
          radius: 5,
          fillColor: 'green'
        }
      });
    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      this.update({
        marker: {
          radius: 3,
          fillColor: 'red'
        }
      });
    }
  },
  name: 'B',
  color: "#b0b0b0",
  data: [
    [46, 56],
    [47, 67],
    [48, 69],
    [50, 55], {
      x: 52,
      y: 57
    }
  ]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/35/

Comment: Thanks. You forgotten to indent 'hover': in your script. http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/21/

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. I've just made the same question again because I didn't remember to have already done it. However, it seems to me that your code is not working anymore. I'm unable to see all the markers change their appearance when hovering the series.

Comment: You don't see them changing to larger green circles on hover?  It's working for me.  Which jsfiddle are you looking at?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/21/ or http://jsfiddle.net/1wfotmoa/23/, it's the same. I see changing only the marker I point to, while I want all the markers changing their appearance.

Comment: Oh, that's different.  To change them all you need to catch the mouseOver and mouseOut events.  Updated answer